# WCF Application throwing error: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: wcf, oracle11g

I have a WCF service that is throwing this error when attempting to write to an Oracle Database.  Anyone have an idea as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being that my Connection string was specifying the incorrect Data Source name.  It has the match the TNSNAMES file on the server, and it didn't.  All is working now.  Hope this helps someone.